# Angular - Interpolación sobre Array

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb, express

estoy haciendo una peticion HTTP de hacia una API donde obtengo en una respuesta, dos resultado. Pero no consigo poder pintar la data en el html.

Peticion HTTP Servicio

```
getCliente(id:string){
    let url = SERVICIOS + '/cliente/' + id
    return this.http.get(url)
  }
```

Componente

```
getCliente(id:string){
    this.clienteService.getCliente(id)
      .subscribe(cliente=>{
        cliente
        console.log(cliente)
      })
  }
```

Modelo:

```
export class Cliente {

    constructor(
        public nombre?: string,
        public direccion?: string,
        public telefono?: string,
        public detalle?: string,
        public user?: string
    ) { }

}

export class Registro {

    constructor(
        public titulo?: string,
        public assigned?: string,
        public status?: string,
        public total?: string,
    ) { }

}
```

Creo entender el motivo, y es que en la peticion le llegan 2 array, ya que la query que hace dicha consulta solicita traer dos datos de dos colleciones ( mongodb ) diferentes con relacion entre si.

Esto son los datos que recibo, como debo manejar los datos desde el componente de angular para mostrar la data en el html?

[image: Petición HTTP]

Edit:

Generando un modelo e unificando los dos en uno conseguir mostrar la data en el HTML pero solo el de cliente

```
export interface ClienteResponse {
    cliente: Cliente;    
    registro: Registro;
}

export interface Cliente {

     nombre?: string,
     direccion?: string,
     telefono?: string,
     detalle?: string,
     user?: string
}

export interface Registro {
     titulo?: string,
     assigned?: string,
     status?: string,
     total?: string,
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="cliente" class="col-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4>{{cliente.cliente.nombre}}</h4>
            <p>{{cliente.cliente.telefono}}</p>
            <p>{{cliente.cliente.direccion}}</p>
            <p>{{cliente.cliente.detalle}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Edit 2 :

Tuve que modificar el componente de cliente de la siguiente manera, para que el modelo de registro se iguale a el cliente que me llega en la respuesta

```
registro: ClienteResponse

      getCliente(id:string){
        this.clienteService.getCliente(id)
          .subscribe((cliente: ClienteResponse)=>{
            this.cliente = cliente,
            this.registro = cliente
            console.log(this.cliente)

          })
      }
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{cliente.registro[0].titulo}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo la respuesta es algo como

```
{
  "cliente": [...],
  "ok": true,
  "registro": [...]
}
```

Por tanto deberías declarar una interfaz para indicar que esa es la respuesta:

```
export interface ClienteResponse {
  cliente: Cliente[];
  ok: boolean;
  registro: Registro[];
}
```

Y usar esta interfaz en tus llamadas:

```
getCliente(id:string): Observable<ClienteResponse> {
  let url = SERVICIOS + '/cliente/' + id;
  return this.http.get<ClienteResponse>(url);
}
```

y en el componente:

```
cliente: ClienteResponse;

getCliente(id:string){
  this.clienteService.getCliente(id)
    .subscribe(cliente => {
      this.cliente = cliente;
      console.log(cliente)
  });
}
```

Esto es sólo para que tengas claro lo que recibes.
En la plantilla HTML, si quieres mostrar esos datos, tendrás que usar algo como:

```
{{ cliente.cliente[0] }}
{{ cliente.registro[0] }}
```

Comment: Haciendo cambios en los modelos e unificando el de registro con el de clientes. Pude mostrar la data del cliente en el HTML, pero el registro el del registro por algun motivo no.

Comment: Por si a alguien le sirve como ejemplo, agregue la solucion y como pude llegar a ella gracias a Pablo. Saludos